# References not working on my computer but fine on colleagues with same solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, reference

I'm currently developing an app on our companies portal and yesterday started noticing that I wasn't able to reference external classes or methods from references.

My colleague put the solution on his computer and committed his code with all the references working fine, and I opened up his code and the references have stopped working and still can't be found.

I have deleted the website cache and other user options but had no luck so far.

One reference file is an external VB class file and the other was simply calling "request" from Web.UI.UserControls. (I got around this by using HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString , even though "Request" worked on my colleagues computer)

Is there any options on my Visual Studio that would make the same code break compared to his? I contemplated a reinstall but it's a lot of time wasted and the problem may surface again.

Edit. I'm on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Comment: Are all of the external references committed into Source Control? Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution.

Comment: where do the references come from? Is it possible that they are loading from the GAC, and your colleague has different versions in the GAC?

Comment: What are "references" in your case? Visual Studio can only reference DLLs, which could be .NET assembly, or COM type library (ActiveX), or native assembly. Which one is yours?

Comment: I've tried a native assembly and a DLL. Again, this is the same solution that works fine on my colleagues but they can't be found on my installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable assembly binding log, and use fuslogvw.exe to see what is going on behind the scenes. It will allow you to know more details on the error and think in possible solutions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to find anything even with the log enabled.

Comment: Do you have the referenced assemblies in the path where the executable lives? If so, have you verified that they have the correct version? Is there any warning in Solution Explorer/References? Any compiler warning?

Comment: To develop here we need to run the solution from our portal, the only errors that are relevant is that the names simply can't be found (where they should be getting found, and DO get found on my colleagues machine). It's exactly the same version of files as we use a central repository.